# Drawing holes in polygons with KML in Google Maps or Earth doesn't work. Somebody has an idea?

Tags: google-maps, kml, polygon, google-earth

This is my kml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
     <name>Pentagon</name>
     <Polygon>
       <extrude>1</extrude>
       <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
       <outerBoundaryIs>
         <LinearRing>
           <coordinates>
             -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100 
             -77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100 
             -77.05315536854791,38.87053267794386,100 
             -77.05552622493516,38.868757801256,100 
             -77.05844056290393,38.86996206506943,100 
             -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
           </coordinates>
         </LinearRing>
       </outerBoundaryIs>
       <innerBoundaryIs>
         <LinearRing>
           <coordinates>
             -77.05668055019126,38.87154239798456,100 
             -77.05542625960818,38.87167890344077,100 
             -77.05485125901024,38.87076535397792,100 
             -77.05577677433152,38.87008686581446,100 
             -77.05691162017543,38.87054446963351,100 
             -77.05668055019126,38.87154239798456,100
           </coordinates>
         </LinearRing>
       </innerBoundaryIs>
     </Polygon>
   </Placemark>
</kml>
```

I import it on Google Maps (my maps), or Google Earth, and the 'hole' isn't displayed. The code is taken from the page [KML Tutorial - Advanced KML Documents](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#advanced_kml)

Answer (score 1):

As of today Google Earth Pro displays the polygon with inner boundary correctly.
However, your file is missing a < Document > element. This may cause problems with other, more strict parsers. Maybe this is the cause of the problem with Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I definitely see an extruded polygon in Google Earth, but it appears as if Google Maps doesn't properly draw the intersection of the `outerBoundaryIs` and `innerBoundaryIs` elements (though I do see an inner border, but not necessarily a polygon with a completely hollow center). I think in this case it seems that Google Maps overlays aren't fully compliant with the KML spec.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the extruded pentagon with a beautiful hole in the middle... but just in Google Earth. In google maps (normal one, without use it through geoxml3) doesn't appear the hole. Probably, as Wyatt Anderson said, Google Maps aren't fully compliant with this KML feature... But if you use geoxml3 you'll get it. I had the same problem and I solved it with geoxml3.js. Good Luck!